# Issues deploying a routed React App to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, github-pages

Like many others, I'm getting stuck on deploying a routed react app to gh pages. The page is just blank - no 404 errors or anything. In the console, I do get some errors like this:

Error      react-dom.production.min.js:189

```
at U (router.ts:5:20)
at ee (hooks.tsx:32:3)
at index.tsx:267:16
at Ei (react-dom.production.min.js:167:137)
at kl (react-dom.production.min.js:193:57)
at xu (react-dom.production.min.js:294:275)
at bc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:389)
at yc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:320)
at vc (react-dom.production.min.js:280:180)
at oc (react-dom.production.min.js:271:88)
```

I have looked over several articles and stack overflow threads on deploying routed apps. I have changed the homepage value to a slightly different order, and I've doublechecked the spelling of the repo. I run npm run deploy, it makes the build folder, gives me a deployment on ghpages, then just a blank screen.

I have put in HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter, I've added a "basename = '/'" to the HashRouter...I have tried putting the title of the homepage (minireddit) in front of all of my route paths in App.js.

I'm hoping some fresh eyes on this will help - I'm sure it's just some silly mistake I'm making, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

App.js:

```
import { HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

(imports for pages/components/styles)

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <NavBar />
      <div className="reddit-container">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <HashRouter basename = "/">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/subreddit/:name" element={<SubReddit />} />
              <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
            </Routes>
          </HashRouter>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <SideBar />
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "minireddit",
  "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/minireddit/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "icons": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the *actual* error you are seeing? Is `index.tsx:267:16` your code? Can you click into the link and inspect the code there? Are `hooks.tsx` and `router.ts` also files belonging to your app?

Comment: In your `HashRouter`'s `basename` prop you are missing a closing ". Is that a typo or it's actually written like that in your code?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Drew. It looks like those files are part of the build folder (I think), as hooks and router are not files that belong to my "normal" file structure. For example, I can click on "hooks" and it takes me to this line:   // TODO: This error is probably because they somehow have 2 versions of the
    // router loaded. We can help them understand how to avoid that.

Comment: typo - it has the closing " in the code. Sigh, that got my hopes up!

Comment: Funny that the link goes to that TODO line because I just noticed that you are using both a `BrowswerRouter` ***and*** a `HashRouter` and the `BrowserRouter` is the outer router so the inner router might not be running correctly. You only need 1 router in the app, so I suggest removing the `BrowserRouter` completely. You may need to specify `basename="/minireddit"` to match the directory the app is running from (*try with and without*), and maybe remove the trailing `"/"` from the `homepage` in package.json, i.e. `"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/minireddit",`.

Comment: I have tried the suggestions - I deployed it first without the Browser Router, then I deployed it again without the BR, with the basename changed, and removed the trailing "/". Unfortunately, the same errors remain in the console (index, router, and hooks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it to work by doing two things (I probably only needed one, but at that point I didn't care why it worked, so long as it finally worked).

1. I changed the BR to HashRouter, and moved it so that it enclosed everything in "container"
2. In index.js, I had deleted <React.StrictMode>. I put that back in.

These two changes worked, though I should go back and see if I can isolate if only one of these was the solution.